# How can I disable "q" in normal state in evil for some modes?

Tags: customize, evil, spacemacs

I'm using Spacemacs. I noticed that in `help-mode`, <kbd>q</kbd> quits, which is exactly what I want. However, in certain other modes, `customize-mode`, for example, <kbd>q</kbd> is bound to `evil-record-macro`. (I set it to start in normal state rather than in emacs state because I like the vim navigation keybindings.) I tried `(evil-define-key 'normal custom-mode-map "q" nil)`, but it didn't rebind.

How can I modify the keybinding so that <kbd>q</kbd> quits as expected?

Answer (score 2):

[Customize](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Easy-Customization.html) appears to be [autoloaded](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Autoload.html), so Emacs won't know about `custom-mode-map` until after you run `customize`.  The following should rebind <kbd>q</kbd> to run `test` in normal state:

```
(defun test ()
  (interactive)
  (message "testing"))

(eval-after-load "custom"
  '(evil-define-key 'normal custom-mode-map "q" #'test))
```

Comment: Rebinding to 'Custom-buffer-done works; rebinding to nil doesn't.

Comment: The reason for this is simple, `evil-define-key` adds an auxiliary keymap which is put on top of, say, `evil-normal-state-map`.  If you bind a command with it, Emacs will notice this and return that command when pressing `q`, if you bind nothing however, Emacs will assume the map shall be disregarded and use the keybinding of the underlying map.

Comment: As a workaround, look up what `q` is bound to in Emacs state, then bind that command with `evil-define-key`.  Also, it's not necessary to wrap it into `eval-after-load` as it is doing something very similiar on its own...

Answer (score 0):

Customize the mode to use `motion` state instead of `normal` state to keep motion keybindings while leaving out `q` for quitting:

```
(evil-set-initial-state 'Custom-mode 'motion)
```

Comment: Clever. Doesn't this break down if I want to go into `insert` state and then press escape?

Comment: Motion state is about moving, not editing text.  `i` isn't bound there.  You could still use `M-x evil-insert-state`, but that would exit to normal state, yes.