# (Evil) Binding "q" to "View-quit" in view mode (instead of "evil-record-macro")

Tags: key-bindings, evil, keymap

I'd like to be able to exit view mode by pressing "q". However, in evil "q" is bound to `evil-record-macro`, even in view mode. I wasn't able to find a solution using `evil-define-key`.

I was excited to find a [similar question here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10726/how-can-i-disable-q-in-normal-state-in-evil-for-some-modes), which proposes using `eval-after-load`, like so:

```
(defun testing ()
  (interactive)
  (message "Testing..."))

(eval-after-load "view" '(evil-define-key 'normal view-mode-map "q" #'testing))
```

This produces some strange behavior. When I enter view mode, `C-h k q` reports the following: "q runs the command evil-record-macro (found in evil-normal-state-map)... It is bound to q.". But, I discovered that if I do press "q", record a macro, and press "q" again to exit the recording, I see the "Testing..." message. Following this, pressing "q" continues to produce the message, and I no longer enter macro recording. "C-h k q" reports: `q runs the command testing... It is bound to q, <normal-state> q.`

Can someone propose a solution or workaround? Thanks!

Comment: By using the [evil-collection](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil-collection) package, you can selectively enable sensible evil keybindings for various modes, including view-mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interestingly enough, Evil *does* define an initial state for `view-mode`, but it won't do anything because `view-mode` is a minor mode and initial states are for major modes only.  The correct way to change the associated state is by using a hook:

```
(add-hook 'view-mode-hook 'evil-motion-state)
```

That way, `q` does the right thing, simply because it is not bound in `evil-motion-state-map` and Emacs looks up the mode-specific key instead.  You can alternatively enter Emacs state by adding `evil-emacs-state` to the hook, like I do for more vanilla behavior.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much.
As an aside, I discovered that the following made my leader key (SPC) work in the \*Messages\* buffer, where previously it did not.

(switch-to-buffer "\*Messages\*")
(evil-motion-state)